# change object column to numeric above cardinality threshold pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is the following an acceptable way to change an object column to numeric if cardinality threshold (cardinality_threshold) is being breached? I think it would be good to check if column values are numeric though. Thanks!

```
data = {
    'col1':['1', '2', '3'],
    'col2':['1', '1', '2'],    
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

cardinality_threshold = 2
cols = [i for i in df.columns]
for i in cols: 
    if(len(df[i].value_counts()) > cardinality_threshold) :
        df[i] = pd.to_numeric(df[i]) # , errors = 'coerce'
        
print(df.info())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use [`DataFrame.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) to vectorize the cardinality check
- Use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to convert `to_numeric` (not vectorized, but more idiomatic than loops)
- Use uppercase for `CARDINALITY_THRESHOLD` per [PEP8 style for constants](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#constants)

```py
CARDINALITY_THRESHOLD = 2

breached = df.columns[df.nunique() > CARDINALITY_THRESHOLD]
df[breached] = df[breached].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

```
>>> df.dtypes
# col1     int64
# col2    object
# dtype: object
```

---

> I think it would be good to check if column values are numeric though.

Note that `to_numeric` [already skips numeric columns](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/06d230151e6f18fdb8139d09abf539867a8cd481/pandas/core/tools/numeric.py#L176-L177), so it's simplest to just let pandas handle it.

If you still want to explicitly exclude numeric columns:

- Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to get the non-numeric columns
- Use [`Index.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) to get the non-numeric breached columns

```py
breached = df.columns[df.nunique() > CARDINALITY_THRESHOLD]
non_numeric = df.select_dtypes(exclude='number').columns
cols = non_numeric.intersection(breached)

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```